# Is there any product to prevent a broken screen's pieces from falling from it?

Tags: display

I just had an accident and broke my MacBook's screen. It still works (there are no "dead" pixels), but I'm worried that some of the broken pieces might fall from the screen. Is there any product could I use to prevent that from happening?

Comment: Something like tape?

Comment: At this point, nothing can make my screen beautiful once again, but I wondered whether there was something that wouldn't make my screen as utterly ugly as tape would.

Comment: I don't suppose you can take a picture?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adhesive_tape) [use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_sensitive_tape) [tape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotch_tape).

[image: image of tape dispenser]

Comment: A whole screen cover with adhesive (not static cling) (like perhaps the [ivisor](http://www.amazon.com/iVisor-Anti-Glare-Protector-Macbook-Unibody/dp/B0029TSTT4)) might work a little better. Since you won't have a bunch of overlapping pieces.

Comment: @Tyler: Well, if the screen is well and truly broken, there's not much you can do anyways.

Comment: It ain't fixed good 'n' proper unless you [use duct tape](http://www.ilaugh.com/red_green_show/handymans_corner/drop_ton_revitalization).